# How to increase allocated table size for particular table using db2 command

Tags: db2, db2-connect

How to increase allocated table size for particular table using DB2 command.Or is there a alternative way to increase memory for all table by 5mb at once.

Comment: Which DB2 platform are you on? The tag "db2-connect" hints at the mainframe. And do you mean on-disk allocation?

Answer (score 0):

you do not increase the memory for the table, but for the tablespace it is located in.

`select tbspace from syscat.tables where tabname = 'MYTAB'`

`db2 "alter tablespace tbspace extend (all 100000)`